# Subscriptions not being fired in SSRS SharePoint integrated mode

Tags: sql-server, sharepoint, reporting-services, subscription

We have a SharePoint farm with SSRS in SharePoint integrated mode. Reports rendering works fine, but suddenly we started to have problems with subscriptions.

The SQL Server agent successfully runs the dbo.AddEvent procedure and a corresponding record occurs in dbo.Event table in the reporting services database. I believe SSRS should pick up these records and run the subscriptions, but it does not (we have a few hundreds of rows in dbo.Event now). Nothing is shown in ExecutionLog3.

We tried to restart the SSRS service, iisreset, restart of the entire farm, nothing helps.

What to do to persuade the SSRS service to process the subscriptions?

We use these versions: MS SQL 2016, SharePoint 2016, Windows server 2016.

Comment: Are you referring to receiving the reports through email? If so I am thinking it is something to do with Exchange, connectivity with it or something similar. Or is it not even getting to that point yet?

Comment: These are subscriptions with SharePoint library and UNC file targets. Since there is nothing in the ExecutionLog3, I think the SSRS service even does not try to render the reports.

Comment: Is the SSRS server set up as a subscription processor? There are config items that determine if the SSRS server (integrated or not) acts as a processor of subscriptions/events. It’s in ReportServer.config.

Comment: @thomas: thanks a lot, I googled some info about the scheduling and delivery processor and may be the problem will be permission related. I also checked the config as you suggested but did not find anything. What exactly should be there? Is it rsreportserver.config file? I did not touch it, so probably the file still has the default content.

Comment: If it is the default file then it will process subscriptions. What do you mean my permissions related? Even if the subscription failed due to permissions something should show up in the ExecutionLog.

Comment: @thomas: based on your comment, I read about Subscriptions and Delivery processor. I found this: *Before the events are processed, the Scheduling and Delivery Processor performs an authentication step to verify that the subscription owner has permission to view the report.* That's why I was suspecting permissions - all of them are owned by one technical user, the customer's scenario is quite specific.

Comment: Does the report server log shed any light on the permission error?

Comment: I checked the Application log in event viewer for source *SQL Server Reporting Services Shared Service*. It only complains about SQLPDW and TERADATA extensions (cannot load). Or do you mean other log?

Answer (score 0):

I finally made it working, but problem is that I do not know what exactly helped. What I did:

- Changed owner of all the subscription to an account with excessive permissions
- Started the Windows service "SPTimerV4" (probably that was the problem?)
- Unprovisioned and provisioned the SSRS service using PowerShell
- Restarted the SSRS service (central administration - manage services on servers, select the server where the SSRS service is running, find it, stop, start)

Now records in dbo.Event do not hang up any more and subscriptions are being processed (and of course hit the ExecutionLog3).

Hope it helps someone.

Thanks to everybody for your help!